# Ubuntu 14.04 Android Studio Panic error when starting avd

Tags: android, ubuntu

I tried everything i found on other forum with no luck.

- I tried running it to root and non-root.
- I tried setting up the environment vars.
- I tried purging android studio and reinstall.
- I can see my avd ini and related files for the avd in /root/.android/avd
- I did change the permission of the files with no result.

I looked everywhere and out of options.

Comment: not related directly, but Genymotion (https://www.genymotion.com/) provide free Android virtual device that is way faster than default AVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6`

Comment: follow the setup guide for android Studio,You will be asked to enable HAXM and download other packages before it runs

Comment: I tried it and it still shows this in the run tab /root/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
PANIC: Could not find Nexus_5_API_21_x86.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd

Comment: I have a Nexus_5_API_21_x86 avd and it doesn't run.

Comment: Try to set the variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to <home directory>\.android\.avd

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after try to install packages?

Comment: I don't think that'd fix it cause the avd's path is $HOME/.android/avd or /root/.android/avd

Comment: I even tried to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME to those values and still not work. thank you for your time btw.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem here. I fixed this by creating a link in my $HOME directory to the /root/.android/avd

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/myuser

$ ln -s /root/.android/avd /home/myuser/.android/avd
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Thanks

Comment: @Mariana Franco a Billion +1 if i could thank you so much you saved me